# Need to create a function to call another function

Tags: c

I need to use this function to access a function named "getName" I have no idea how to do that as I have tried a couple of times but no success. Please help me out a little

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

struct Contact {

    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers number;
};
void getName(struct Name *name);


void getContact(struct Contact *contact);
void getName(struct Name *name)
{
    char Initial;
    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf("%s" , name->firstName);


}


 void getContact(struct Contact *);
```

- This function does not return a value but has one parameter that receives a pointer to a
  Contact.
- The purpose of this function is to set the values for a Contact using the pointer
  parameter variable (set the Contact it points to).
- Use the pointer parameter received to this function to supply the appropriate Contact member to the “get” functions (getName) to set the values for the Contact.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: getName(&contact);

Comment: I know it's wrong but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `getName(struct Name *name)` expects a `struct Name`, not `struct Contact`

Comment: but it still gives me an error

Comment: What was the error? Please include that in your question.

Comment: if I do getName(&name);                It says  'name' undeclared (first use in this function)      each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: Did you define an instance of `Struct Name name` before `getName(&name)`.

Comment: that I did in the struct contact

Comment: Okay, then this is probably what you want, access the `Struct Name` member in `Struct Contact`: `getName(&contact.name);`.

Comment: another error request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Define a variable first:  struct Contact cnt; getName(&cnt.name);

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do this. You pass the pointer to the `struct` variable you want to make change to. And then get input accordingly.

```
struct Contact contact;
...
...
getContact(&contact);
```

Then in `getContact()`

```
void getContact(struct Contact *contact){
    getName(&(contact->name));
    ...
}
```

In `getName()`

```
void getName(struct Name *name){
    if( scanf("%30s",name->firstName)!= 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in input" );
    }
 }
```

Here the key idea is we are passing address of the variables to the function and then making changes to the variable dereferrencing it.

Here a basic set of operations is shown. You can extend on it to get more inputs. This answer provides the basic way to do that.